# I want to recompile a package with python3

Tags: python, python3

I need to recompile a package on slackware using python3 instead python2.7
I have tried to set a link python3->python but doesn't work.
[This](http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.1/python/pyside/pyside.SlackBuild) is the slackbuild wich i use

Comment: Why? Thy system requirements are `python-2.6` or better

Comment: I have two python version 2.7 and 3.0 i want to preserve both